Чи "інтегроване розроблювальне середовище" це прийнятний переклад для IDE?
Горох подає розроблювальний як пасив.
Я ще думав про розробляльний:
рятувати - рятувальний
розробляти - розробляльний
Як воно правильніше?

"розроблюване" не існує такого слова в українській мові. "інтегроване середовище розробки" буде прийнятним.

@RomanMikhol Розроблення і розробка
В українській мові для позначення процесу рекомендовано уникати скалькованих віддієслівних іменників жіночого роду.

@RomanMikhol Тобто розробка це результат процесу.

«Розробляльний» мені не подобається.
По-перше, таке слово ніде не вживається (жодного трапляння в Google) — на відміну від «розроблювальний» (яке хоч і не дуже часто, але вживається).
По-друге, аналогом «рятувальний» буде радше якраз «розроблювальний» (а не «розробляльний»). Бо «рятувальний» вже містить оте -ува-/-юва- (але не має пари без -ува-/-юва-). Приклади:
• рознізняти — розрізняльний, розрізнювати — розрізнювальний;
• розробляти — розробляльний, розроблювати (таке слово є) — розроблювальний;
• рятати — рятальний, рятувати — рятувальний;
• спричиняти — спричиняльний, спричинювати — спричинювальний;
• тощо.
По-третє, IDE використовують постійно (повторювано/тривале), тому теоретично -ува-/-юва- тут здається доречним.
Я навіть думаю, що на Горосі описка, з великою імовірністю у тій таблиці мало бути «розроблюваний — разрабатываемый», а не «розроблюваЛЬний — разрабатываемый».
Також Караванський подає як актив.

обрабатывающий що /мн. хто/ обробля́є тощо, ста́вши розробля́ти, зда́тний оброби́ти, для обро́бки, за́йня́тий розро́бкою, обро́бник, обро́блювач, прикм. обро́бний, обро́блювальний, розро́блювальний, опрацьо́вувальний, обкру́чувальний;
разраба́тывающий що /мн. хто/ розробля́є тощо, зда́тний розробляти, ра́ди́й розроби́ти, для розро́бки, за́йня́тий розробкою, розро́блювач, розро́бник, прикм. розро́бний, розро́бчий, розро́блювальний, опрацьо́вувальний, відпрацьо́вувальний, випрацьо́вувальний, добува́льний;


То "інтегроване розроблювальне середовище" — це прийнятний переклад? Бачу що є багато аргументів, але нажаль нема чіткого висновку. Дякую!

Інтегроване середовище розробки (integrated development environment або IDE) - це комплекс програмних рішень, за допомогою яких відбувається розробка нових цифрових програмних продуктів.

Розробка програмного забезпечення (англ. software engineering, software development) — це рід діяльності (професія) та
процес, спрямований на створення та підтримку працездатності, якості
та надійності програмного забезпечення, використовуючи технології,
методологію та практики з інформатики, керування проєктами,
математики, інженерії та інших областей знання.

Термін "розробка" в українській мові зазвичай вживається на позначення процесу інтелектуальної творчості людини, пов'язаної зі створенням цифрових продуктів (розробка ПЗ, розробка логотипу, розробка сайту, розробка алгоритму) або результатів такої діяльності (розробка, винахід).
Термін "розроблення" зазвичай вживається на позначення інженерно-аналітичних робіт, повʼязаних з виготовленням еталонних екземплярів приладів і устаткування (розро́блення проду́кції), а також на позначення комплексу робіт з промислового видобутку корисних копалин (розроблення родовищ нафти і газу).
Терміни розроблення, розроблювання, розробляння, розробка семантично споріднені. Отже, при побудові речення можна вжити різні дієслівні форми, які якнайкраще відповідатимуть контексту.

Розроблення можна вжити тільки для виготовлення першого приладу, коли його розробляють, а для дальшого масового виробництва це слово не підходить. І хоч Вікіпедія це не АД все ж стаття розроблення продукції саме про цей початковий етап утворення першого виробу й говорить.

@Yola, згоден з вашою думкою. Після етапу розроблення крокує випуск продукціі. І це стосується саме матеріальних речей. Коли йдеться про цифровий продукт, на першому етапі відбувається розробка і надалі оновлення. Покращив відповідь.
